# Nokogiri gem fails to install in OS X Mavericks

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, osx-mavericks

Install fails showing:

```
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
checking for libiconv_open() in -liconv... no
libiconv is missing.
```

However, looking at nokogiri's mkmf.log, the following errors are shown:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28/lib/libxslt.dylib, **file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)**: /usr/local/Cellar/libxslt/1.1.28/lib/libxslt.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib/libxml2.dylib, **file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)**: /usr/local/Cellar/libxml2/2.9.1/lib/libxml2.dylib

ld: warning: ignoring file /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.dylib, **file was built for x86_64 which is not the architecture being linked (i386)**: /usr/local/Cellar/libiconv/1.14/lib/libiconv.dylib
```

I have xcode and it's command tools installed.
My ~/.bash_profile has 64bit compiling forced by: export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

I have libxml2, libxslt, and libiconv installed via Homebrew, and each is linked.
I've tried installing all of these without the ARCHFLAG in .bash_profile.

I've also brew install apple-gcc42 and linked, as per how tos I've found.

I've tried installing nokogiri by passing paths to libxml2, libxslt, and libiconv in /usr/local/Cellar/, but the install still fails, with same errors as above.

I've wasted at least a day on this - just trying to get one Ruby gem installed. I'd really like to get back to actually developing.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 21):

Setting `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1` before actually installing the gem did the trick for me.

Summarising:

- If previously installed, uninstall the gem:
  `$ gem uninstall nokogiri`
- Use Homebrew to install `libxml2`, `libxslt` and `libiconv` if needed:
  `$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`
- Install the gem specifying the paths to the libraries to be linked against:
  `$ NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries --with-iconv-dir="$(brew --prefix libiconv)" --with-xml2-config="$(brew --prefix libxml2)/bin/xml2-config" --with-xslt-config="$(brew --prefix libxslt)/bin/xslt-config"`

Comment: +1  `NOKOGIRI_USE_SYSTEM_LIBRARIES=1 gem install nokogiri` was sufficient to get this to install for me.  This really should be fixed, installs should not be this difficult. I use real nokogiri saws such as dozuki saws and using them to cut dovetails isn't this much trouble.

Comment: +1 for this solution, worked for me too (the official tutorial didn't), however here's the link: http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html

Answer (score 0):

- Check if HomeBrew is installed correctly with the appropriate XCode command line tools.

brew doctor

- You can also check via XCode > Preferences

With valid command line tools installed, I was able to resolve the nokogiri error encountered after the OSX Maverick upgrade.

Also found that some of the 'brew' packages were outdated after the OS X Mountain Lion to Maverick upgrade. (e.g. qt, postgresql)

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me:

1. If you haven't already done so, install the XCode developer tools: `$ xcode-select --install`
2. Use homebrew to install (or reinstall) libxml2, libxslt and libiconv: `$ brew install libxml2 libxslt libiconv`
3. Install nokogiri: `gem install nokogiri -- --with-iconv-dir=/usr/local/opt/libiconv`

I found the solution I needed in an [unmerged pull request](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri.org-tutorials/pull/26/files) to update the Nokogiri tutorials. I recommend that if someone else encounters this issue and has exhausted the solutions here, check that [pull request list](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri.org-tutorials/pulls) to see if someone has submitted an update to the instructions on the Nokogiri tutorials page.

Answer (score 0):

From [github page](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/1111)
First, you should:
 xcode-select --install
and then re-install nokogiri.
That worked for me while another suggestion didn't. Hope this helps someone else.